# cocos2d-js: How to set viewport orientation (landscape / portrait)?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

How can I set the viewport orientation in cocos2d-js 3.0?

I found the variables

```
cc.UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
cc.UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
cc.UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
cc.UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
```

in CCInputManager.js but no function to actually set them.

And I found this description:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Device_Orientation

but it is different for Android and iOS and that contradicts the cocos run  command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android just edit the file

```
frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

in the project directory. Change

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

to

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change in your project config.json

```
    {
     "init_cfg":{
    "isLandscape": false,
     "isPotrait":true,
     "isWindowTop": false,
     "name": "untitled",

    "width": 960,
    "height": 640,
   "entry": "main.js",
   "consolePort": 6050,
   "uploadPort": 6060,
   "debugPort": 5086
},
```